# Passing Search Filter parameter in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have Search Filter Parameter
like

```
public struct PaperAdFilterParameter : IPaperAdFilterParameter
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int PublisherID { get; set; }
        public int PublishTypeID { get; set; }
        public int AdCategoryID { get; set; }
        public int EditionID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

    }
```

and i want to pass thru Web API ,My code is

```
 string url = PaperAdUrl.FormatWith("GetListBy?" + paperAdFilterParameter);

            try
            {
                using (var client = WebServer.HttpClient)
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    if (paperAdFilterParameter.ID.IsNotEmpty())
                    {
                        PaperAd paperAd = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PaperAd>();
                        paperAdList.Add(paperAd);
                    }
                    else
                    paperAdList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<PaperAd>>();
                }
            }
```

and contoller

```
[HttpGet, Route("GetListBy")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetListBy([FromUri] PaperAdFilterParameter ipaperAdFilterParameter)
        {


            var paperAdList = await _paperAdService.GetListAsync(ipaperAdFilterParameter);

            if (paperAdList.IsNull())
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(paperAdList);
        }
```

I dont know how to pass parameter?

Comment: is the middle code block meant to simulate like a test. Are you asking how to add the paperAdFilterParameter object to the request string?

Comment: yes Seabizkit,i want to pass object to the request string or fromUri

Comment: How does the `PaperAdUrl.FormatWith` method look like?